# How to update task status

Tags: c#, .net, api, soap, salesforce

Can anyone plz shed some light on why the following code doesn't change task status, even though the call returns with a success message:

```
public bool markTaskCompleted(String id)
{
        try
        {
            sObject UpdateTask = new sObject();
            UpdateTask.type = "Task";

            UpdateTask.Id = id;

            System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            XmlElement afield = doc.CreateElement("Status");
            XmlText txtNode = doc.CreateTextNode("Completed");
            afield.AppendChild(txtNode);

            SaveResult[] saveResults = binding.update(new sObject[] { UpdateTask });

            if (saveResults[0].success)
                return true;
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < saveResults[0].errors.Length; i++)
                {
                    Error err = saveResults[0].errors[i];
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Errors were found on item 0" + Environment.NewLine +
                                                            "Error code: " + err.statusCode.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                                                            "Error message: " + err.message);
                }

                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("An unexpected error has occurred: " + e.Message + " Stack trace: " + e.StackTrace);
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, where is task status being changed and why is saveresults an array? Maybe you're checking the wrong element for success?

Comment: @Sico: What do u mean? Status is the only thing I'm updating in the above code (setting it to Completed), and saveResults is an array becuz that is what SalesForce API function returns, otherwise it would have been a compile-time error.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise it was SalesForce specific code. Glad you found your answer

Comment: Hi @dotNet, looks like you've already figured this one out, but so you're aware there is a new stackexchange site specific to Salesforce at salesforce.stackexchange.com. Come join the community over there! :) As a reference there are about 4x the questions on the new stackexchange as compared to SO and a lot more active participants.

Comment: @Ralph: Thanks a bunch. That sure was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it myself. I was missing the following critical line:

```
UpdateTask.Any = new System.Xml.XmlElement[] { afield };
```

This line should be added immediately after the `afield.AppendChild(txtNode);` line. Now it is updating the status just fine.